# Fractional vertical scrolling

Tags: scrolling

I found this [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Vertical-Scrolling.html#:%7E:text=Vertical%20fractional%20scrolling%20means%20shifting,number%2C%20never%20less%20than%20zero.) About fractional verticle scrolling for emacs. However there was not any explanation about how to configure this for scrolling of normal files.

How do I configure a fractional scroll step? I am thinking of implementing a smooth scrolling configuration.

Answer (score 3):

That's to be expected because this is the Emacs Lisp reference, not the Emacs manual.  It explains how a developer can adjust the vertical scrolling in a fine-grained way.

Emacs 26.1 introduced `pixel-scroll-mode` which demonstrates this capability.